# Serializable class with unserializable injected member in JAVA

Tags: java, guice

I have a serializable class which has some members injected from guice module. However, these members are unserializable and I can't force the declaration of them with Serializable interface.
How shall I write readObject and writeObject functions for this class to support the serializing the instance of this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either declare these fields as `transient` to prevent automatic serialization or implement your own `readObject` and `writeObject`. The implementation will depend on your application. If after deserialization you can stand without the not serializable members, just ignore them. If you need them you have to find a way to get them.

In your case these are Guice-injected objects. If you are planning to deserialize your object in context of Guice you have to inject these dependencies. I do not know Guice enough but in Spring I know 2 ways:

1. fetch these object programmatically from current Spring (Guice in your case) application context.
2. Spring has factory that can inject all needed dependencies itself. I believe that Guice should have similar functionality.